# How can I design an "analog" reminder scheduling system for a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, interface

I'm working with a mobile app and **would like the user to easily and intuitively set up 3+ reminders in-app.** Just about every example that i saw up to date uses HH:MM time picker, which seems too cumbersome and precise for me. There's no way to easily adjust all reminders at once for a particular day.

[image]

This is why I've been playing around with an idea of a "24 hour analog" reminder scheduling using drag and drop:

- Reminder pin with an icon representing reminder type (ex: exercise)
- Drag and drop gesture to place a reminder pin,
- Pan gesture to modify timing of a reminder (moves pin around)
- Rotate gesture can be used to adjust timing of all reminders at once (for example if a user woke up late one day)

**How can I set time in analog format, without using a time picker, in a mobile setting?** Are such systems intuitive to use?

Here's my earliest attempt at creating such a time picker (all reminders are fixed, and a rotate gesture is used to select bedtime)
[image]

Another example that I'm aware of is my own [ios journal app focused around a 24 hour dial](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/5-in-1-journal-food-sleep/id493734139?mt=8) to show when different journal entries took place. I'm thinking of modifying that app into such reminder scheduling system.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea that might help or give an other perspective.

Old conventions are often intuitive until the point where your target audience is to young to remember.

Analog clocks work by rotating the wheel, just one wheel. You have to keep turning it until you reached the right time.
Intuitive? Most likely, but efficient? Not really.

To perhaps make it more efficient you could let the user start at the desired hour and then rotate to adjust the minutes.
For example: if the user starts the tap/drag at the number 8 and then rotate it clockwise to let's say the number 3 it will be 8:15.

The problem: how do you indicate am or pm?
A switch perhaps?